# Ascii to Hex conversion in Xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a requirement to convert the ASCII to Hex String using XQuery, Please help to provide any respective reference or code snippets to achieve this functionality, by example I have then string: `1239565447854` and I need convert to hex: `31323339353635343437383534`

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string-to-codepoints()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-to-codepoints) to get the numeric codepoint for each character. For each codepoint, determine how many times it is divisible by 16 using [`idiv`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-numeric-integer-divide), and the remainder using the [`mod`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-numeric-mod) operator. For both of those numbers, get their hex value by looking up by position in a sequence of the 16 characters and then join the results:

```
declare function local:codepoint-to-hex($codepoint as xs:integer) as xs:string {
  let $hex-index := ("0123456789ABCDEF" => string-to-codepoints()) ! codepoints-to-string(.)
  let $base16 := $codepoint idiv 16
  let $remainder := $codepoint mod 16
  return 
    string-join((
      $hex-index[$base16 + 1],
      if ($remainder = 0) 
      then ()
      else $hex-index[$remainder + 1]
      ), "")
};

declare function local:string-to-hex($str as xs:string) as xs:string {
  string-join( string-to-codepoints($str) ! local:codepoint-to-hex(.), "")
};

local:string-to-hex('1239565447854')
```